# In the answer to the question attached below, I don't quite see how step-3 is derived from step-2, Can anyone explain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

[Calculating the expected values of the min/max of 2 random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82945/calculating-the-expected-values-of-the-min-max-of-2-random-variables)

Consider two fair $k$-sided dice with the numbers 1 through $k$ on their faces, obtaining values $X_1$ and $X_2$. What is $\mathbb{E}[\max(X_1, X_2)]$ and what is $\mathbb{E}[\min(X_1, X_2)]$.

**And the answer to this question as posted in the link above is**

**HINT**: $\min(x_1,x_2) + \max(x_1,x_2) = x_1 + x_2$, so it is enough to evaluate either expected value. Also $\max(x_1,x_2) - \min(x_1,x_2) = \vert x_2-x_1\vert$. Therefore, finding $\mathbb{E}(\vert X_2-X1 \vert)$ allows to determine expectations needed:

$$ \begin{eqnarray}
   \mathbb{E}\left( \vert X_2- X_1\vert \right) &=& \sum_{n_1=1}^k \sum_{n_2=1}^k \mathbb{P}(X_1=n_1) \mathbb{P}(X_2=n_2) \vert n_2 - n_1 \vert \\ &=& 
   2 \sum_{n_2=1}^k \sum_{n_1=1}^{n_2-1} \mathbb{P}(X_1=n_1) \mathbb{P}(X_2=n_2) (n_2 - n_1 ) \\ &=& 
   2 \sum_{n_2=1}^k \sum_{n_1=1}^{n_2-1} \mathbb{P}(X_1=n_1) \mathbb{P}(X_2=n_2-n_1) n_1
  \end{eqnarray}
$$

**I don't understand how step three in the above answer is derived**

Comment: Maybe better to put the question in the post, not a link.

Comment: Thanks added the question. Do you see how it is derived?

Comment: Was it necessary to ask this here instead of waiting for an answer to appear on the other page (which should happen soon)?

Answer (score 0):

The order of the inner summation is reversed. In other words, it is a substitution 
$$n_1\ \rightarrow\ n_2-n_1.$$

Comment: But that doesn't explain the changes in the arguments of the probabilities, where $n_1$ has remained unchanged and $n_2$ has changed. Even if we swap them it doesn't work out.

Comment: You are right, it seems like it should be $P(X_1=n_2)$.

Comment: I still don't see how the indices can be resubstituted can you explain please?

Comment: I believe that the last expression it should say $P(X_1=n_2)$ in stead of $P(X_1=n_1)$, which you get by the substitution above and interchanging $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Comment: I don't know why, it seems rather convoluted to me, but perhaps it will be of some use further down the derivation. And sure, substitution is fine any time, and often useful in summations.